# Array initialization error #define

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, c-preprocessor

I am initializing an array using `#define`s in C, but I keep getting error "Expected an Expression"

Following is code snippet

```
#include "File2.h"
File 1.h
Int32 dataBuff[SCRATCH_BUFF_SZ];
```

File2.h

```
#define SCRATCH_BUFF_SZ (             SAMP_BUFF_LEN \
                                    + CORR_BUFF_LEN \
                                    + KERNEL_BUFF_LEN \
                                    + CE_BUFF_LEN \
                          )
```

I dont understand what is wrong here. Error is pointing to `#define` directive as "Expected an Expression" on each parameter line of Macro def

Comment: whats samp,corr,kernel, ce defined as?  and is that in32 declaration inside a .h??  or a .c?

Comment: Hi thanks for reply,SAMP_BUFF_LEN \
                                    + CORR_BUFF_LEN \
                                    + KERNEL_BUFF_LEN \
                                    + CE_BUFF_LEN \

Comment: are defined as #defines in File3.h

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

1. Are you including File3.h before you create databuff?
2. Look at the output from the prepocessor. With gcc, you can do this with the -E flag.

Answer (score 0):

Expected an Expression: An operator such as + or = requires an expression for its right operand, but no recognizable expression appears.

Make sure there is no new line between your macros `(macro is not broken)` in SCRATCH_BUFF_SZ

Comment: any special character? (be careful with the spaces also) Verify all your macros. SAMP_BUFF_LEN, CORR_BUFF_LEN, KERNEL_BUFF_LEN, CE_BUFF_LEN

Comment: Verify the order of your .h files. As your preprocessor is in .h. Make sure you have included header file for your other macros

Answer (score 0):

my guess is one of your #defined constants in SCRACTCH_BUFF_SZ is not defined as you think?

ie

SAMP_BUFF_LEN 
 CORR_BUFF_LEN 
 KERNEL_BUFF_LEN 
 CE_BUFF_LEN

are not what you think perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I double checked every thing keeping your comments in view.
It was a compiler configuration error.

I am using Code Composer Studio. I checked preprocessor option in it and now it works fine.

I should have tried on other compiler to isolate the problem.

appreciate your time!
Thanks